# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx - CatchAll TLS - How to load correct cert?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cert-manager

I have a web application that allows whitelabeling where user can add their domain, forward DNS and load it application when users domain is loaded.

I am forwarding to my application form ingress nginx using `catchAll` technique. Here is the ingress.yml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: linkfy-frontend-ingress
  namespace: linkfy
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.tld
      secretName: example.tld 
  rules:
    - host: example.tld
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
    - host: "" # catchAll
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

This method works perfectly. non secure requests `http` routes to frontend from any domain that is pointed to the load balancer.

However I need to support tls as well. Hosts doesn't support blank string "" or asterisk "*"

Note: I am able to use cert manager to create tls certs from my application. Creation of certificates working perfectly.

Only challenge is to load that certificate matching with a incoming domain (catchAll).

If I have example2.tld I need to load the cert that is created for example2.tld.